# Use javascript variable in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use js variables in c# code?

This is my model:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my cshtml:

```
@model List<inspinia.models.Department>
<select name="DepartmentId" class="form-control" id="Department">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Department").on("change", function () {
      var DepartmentId = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
      //the problem in the next line. 
      @foreach(var item in Model.Where(x=>x.ParentId==@:DepartmentId))
        {
            @:alert(@item.id)
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Well I am having error when I use

```
Model.Where(x=>x.ParentId==@:JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE).
```

Is there any way to do it or I definitely have to use ajax ?

Comment: Consider that the C# runs on the server while the page is being served, and the JavaScript runs on the client after the C# has fully executed - it's simply not possible to mix them in this fashion.  You'll need to look into loading data dynamically, eg by using ajax requests.

Comment: You're confusing client-side and server-side code.  They run at completely different times and in completely different contexts.  You'll either need to emit all of the items to the page and conditionally act upon them in JavaScript code, or make an AJAX request from JavaScript code to fetch the items you need after the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, because the javascript code's is for clientside and razor in serverside.

> You have two solutions:

1- Put all departement in `list(<ul>)` and use JQuery for get your data on change

2- Use jquery ajax and get data directly from controller(create controller for that)